# Rotate between colors in String

Tags: java, string, algorithm, colors

I'm trying to create a `String` that rotates color. Every letter has a different `color`, and they need to rotate in a linear manner. The text will go inside of a `JLabel`.

I built the text so that it could be created given a word and an array of colors (Strings).

```
String[] colors = {"white", "blue", "red"};
String word = "foo";
String coloredText;

String[] letters = word.split("(?!^)"); //split text into indiv. letters

        coloredText = "<html>";

        for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < letters.length; i++, j++){

            if(j >= colors.length)
                j=0;

            coloredText += String.format("<font color='%s'> %s </font>", colors[j], letters[i]);
        }

        coloredText += "</html>";
```

This will result in a string that has foo with a white `F`, blue `O` and red final `O`.

Of course if there were less colors than letters, they would just keep on rotating.

Now I have a `timer` to rotate the colors, but I can't figure out the `algorithm` to do it. 
Basically, every color should take the place of the following one, with the last one replacing the first.

**So for example:**

[image]

Of course this has to work for any number of given letters and colors, with the colors that don't fit being ignored. (A word of 3 letters with 10 colors will only use the first 3 colors).

I have tried using `.replace()` but `regex` is a bit too difficult for me.

Any idea?

Comment: Keep the index of the color you used for the first letter in a field, and decrement it each time you color your string. If it reached -1, reset it to the last index. First round is 0, so you end up with WBR. Then you decrement it. Since it becomes -1, you set it to 2, and you end up with RWB. Then you decrement it, and you end up with BRW.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have an additional integer (class or instance variable, depending on your code) as an offset counter between 0 and colors.length-1.

```
int offset = 0
```

Every time your timer executes, increment the offset by 1 and check if your offset overflows the allowed offset. If so, reset it to 0.

```
void onTimerExecutes(){
    offset++;
    if (offset >= colors.length)
        offset = 0;
    applyColorsToText();
}
```

Then add the offset to your `j`:

```
j = offset;
for(int i = 0, i < letters.length; i++, j++)
```

Comment: The offset should be decremented to rotate the way OP wanted

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can skip some lines if you don't reset the offset to 0 but index the array with the modulus operator. See [Modulus Operator](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~clin/MoreJava/Intro/expr-mod.html)

So you'd have

```
void onTimerExecutes(){
offset++;
applyColorsToText();
}
```

and in the for loop

```
            coloredText += String.format("<font color='%s'> %s </font>",    colors[offset%colors.length], letters[i]);
```

If you want to rotate the other way around, decrement your offset instead:

```
offset = 0;
void onTimerExecutes(){
offset--;
applyColorsToText();
}
```

and use [Math.floorMod(int, int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#floorMod-int-int-), so:

```
            coloredText += String.format("<font color='%s'> %s </font>",    colors[Math.floorMod(offset, colors.length)], letters[i]);
```